# Deleting remote master branch, refused due to being the current branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

How do I delete a remote master branch from GitHub/Bitbucket?

I'm trying:

```
# git push bb --delete master
remote: bb/acl: user is allowed. accepted payload.[K
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master[K
To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/reponame.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/reponame.git'
```

Also I tried

```
git push bb :master
```

But all this does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cant delete a remote master branch on git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208751/i-cant-delete-a-remote-master-branch-on-git)

Comment: @cirosantilli So what should I do?

Comment: If you agree with the duplicate status, it is best to make an edit and say you agree. If you disagree, please explain on a comment why you disagree. I have already flagged, so it is already on a review list for "big rep" poeple to vote upon duplicate status. In any case, even if marked as duplicate you won't lose any rep.

Comment: @cirosantilli I cannot find button, which allows me to agree.

Comment: There is no specific button, I meant just edit the post. But a comment works too, so need anymore.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Note: for **Bitbucket**, you would change the default branch by accessing the settings of your repository, and changing the branch at the  "**`Main branch`**" combo box.

[image: Main branch on Bitbucket]

Once the main branch is no longer master, then [you can push and remove master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191620/6309).

[MarsAndBack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4378314/marsandback) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040754/deleting-remote-master-branch-refused-due-to-being-the-current-branch/14042998#comment120599570_14042998) this applies to GitHub as well.

Comment: FYI now in 2020 this is only possible for the admin of the repo (which might not be you!)

Comment: @Sliq Good to know indeed. I suppose if you are the owner of the repository, you would be able to perform this operation.

Comment: This applied to Github as well. After I set default branch to something else, I was able to delete the original branch.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: This requires to push another branch to remove the master and `bitbucket` automatically creates `master` branch with `.gitignore` file as a first commit upon a repo creation. You have to deselect `Include '.gitignore'` to avoid that in first place.

Comment: @Andry OK. "deselect Include .gitignore" to avoid that `.gitignore` to be created. Makes sense.

Answer (score 90):

In the **settings** block on the **options** tap in the **settings** page (well, just click on the *Settings* tab on your GitHub repository page), you are able to change the default branch (you need to have the other default branch on GitHub as well).

[image: Change default branch on GitHub]

After you have done that, you are able to remove it:

```
$ git push bb :master
```

Comment: And you have to be the administrator to be able to make such changes.

Answer (score 5):

Before deleting a branch, you have to make sure that the branch being deleted is not the default branch. In Github, go to repository settings: [image]

Find **Default branch** and switch the default branch:

[image]

Now you can run the following to delete the remote branch.

```
git push origin --delete <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 3):

In **2021**:

- go to Repository Settings
  [image: Repository Settings menu item image]
- scroll down to Advanced
- scroll down to Main Branch
- choose the new branch from the dropdown

[image]

Then, run your git change command, eg `git push bb --delete master`

or, in my case, `git push origin :master main`

*Note: You'll have to be the repository's administrator to make changes like this.*

Answer (score 1):

I did it :

1. create a new branch.
2. change it to main branch ( need refresh )
3. remove master

in BitBucket goto repository details then Advanced then change main branch

[image]

then you can delete master from branches in main menu

then you can create master again from your one of branches then reconfigure Master branch as master