# Failed to execute git clone in composer

Tags: json, git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to install something that I created on git in my laravel site and I keep getting this error when I hit composer update I have git version 2.0.1 and my mac is version 10.8.5

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@bitbucket.org:PATH-TO-REPO.git' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-modules/vendor/test/tinymce' && cd '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-modules/vendor/test/tinymce' && git
>      remote add composer 'git@bitbucket.org:PATH-TO-REPO.git' && git fetch composer
>     dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
>       Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
>       Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>     dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
>       Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
>       Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>     sh: line 1:   504 Trace/BPT trap: 5       git clone --no-checkout 'git@bitbucket.org:PATH-TO-REPO.git' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-modules/vendor/test/tinymce'

In my composer.json I have

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.6",
    "test/tinymce": "dev-master",
    "test/uploadify": "dev-master",
    "mews/captcha": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/modules"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url":  "http://localhost:8888/test-modules/packages.json"
    }
]
}
```

and in my packages.json

```
{
"packages": {
    "test/tinymce": {
        "dev-master": {
            "name": "test/tinymce",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@bitbucket.org:PATH-TO-REPO.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    },
    "test/uploadify": {
        "dev-master": {
            "name": "test/uploadify",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@bitbucket.org:PATH-TO-REPO.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a linking error. Tried to reinstall git?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private composer packages - no valid composer.json was found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927250/private-composer-packages-no-valid-composer-json-was-found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git commands not working in Mac terminal: "dyld: Symbol not found: \_\_\_strlcpy\_chk" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-commands-not-working-in-mac-terminal-dyld-symbol-not-found-strlcpy-ch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git commands not working in Mac terminal: "dyld: Symbol not found: \_\_\_strlcpy\_chk" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-commands-not-working-in-mac-terminal-dyld-symbol-not-found-strlcpy-ch)

Answer (score 0):

> dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk

You need to re-install your Git. On macOS, use [Brew](https://brew.sh/), e.g.: `git reinstall git`. This is usually the issue when your program points to the wrong or outdated libraries.