# git push command gave unexpected output

Tags: git

I tried to push changes in my local branch(local_dev) to a remote branch(develop), I used below command, but it gave me an unexpected message after executing the command.

```
$ git push origin local_dev :develop
```

message after command execution:

```
Counting objects: 1941, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (838/838), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1378/1378), 265.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1378 (delta 604), reused 863 (delta 257)
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/develop
To https://github.com/MyCompany/MyProject.git
 * [new branch]      local_dev -> local_dev
 ! [remote rejected] develop (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyCompany/MyProject.git'
```

Any suggestions on this why this should happen?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting remote master branch, refused due to being current branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040754/deleting-remote-master-branch-refused-due-to-being-current-branch)

Comment: It may look like a duplicate, however I was not trying to delete a branch, just wanted to push my changes to another branch. Glad I didn't have access to delete that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in the refspec. It should be this:

```
git push origin local_dev:develop
```

and not this

```
git push origin local_dev :develop
```

Because that space is there, you're giving `git push` two refspecs, not one. The first spec says "push `local_dev` to the remote with the name `local_dev`". The second spec says `:develop`, and since the left-hand side of `:` is empty, it means "delete the remote `develop` branch". That's why you get this last line in your `git push` output:

> ```
> ! [remote rejected] develop (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
> ```

For more information on deleting branches with `:<branch>` syntax, please read,

- [Pro Git § 9.5 Git Internals - The Refspec: Deleting References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#Deleting-References).

Comment: Hmmm...didn't realize git can punish you so hard for an extra space. :). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @YellowDiamond never underestimate the importance of whitespace in programming `:P`

Comment: you right. trying to accept your answer says 2 more minutes before you can accept.